# Django - Accordion unordered-list

Tags: django, python-3.x, accordion, unordered

I have to make an unordered list for an accordion-menu where the last "leaf" of the tree has to have a specific url.

These datas will be grabbed from the "Category"s model:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')
```

So, as you can see here, we have a "parent" and a "children".
If a certain Category hasn't a parent it will be "None", same for the children (if it hasn't a children, it will be "None" aswell).

Based on this model, i have to "create" an unordered list and display it as an accordion.

Kind of:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a>Category 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a>SubCategory 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="foo/">SubSubCategory 1</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a>Category 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="foo/">SubCategory 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've read about [unordered-list](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#unordered-list), but doesn't seem to be the thing i need, so i tried to make something by myself.

```
class ProductsListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'main/products.html'
    paginate_by = 9
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'items'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['brands'] = Brand.objects.all()

        self.html = ''
        self.make_accordion(Category.objects.all())

        context['html'] = self.html

        return context

    def make_accordion(self, categories, parent=None):
        for category in [cat for cat in categories if cat.parent == parent]:
            is_children = category.children.exists()

            if not is_children:
                self.html += '<li><a href="/products/category/{}">{}</a>'.format(
                    category.id, category.name
                )
            else:
                self.html += '<li><a>{}</a>'.format(category.name)

            if is_children:
                self.html += '<ul>'

            self.make_accordion(categories, category)

            if is_children:
                self.html += '</ul>'

            self.html += '</li>'
```

This code takes too much time, like 10 seconds before the page will be displayed. Is there any way to do what i actually need to do?

EDITED:

```
class ProductsListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'main/products.html'
    paginate_by = 1
    model = Product
    context_object_name = 'items'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['brands'] = Brand.objects.all()

        self.html = ''

        # Get each category, by making a list of tuples
        self.categories = Category.objects.values_list('pk', 'name', 'parent__pk')
        self.make_unordered_list()

        context['html'] = self.html

        return context

    def get_children(self, parent):
        for pk, name, parent_pk in self.categories:
            if parent_pk == parent:
                yield (pk, name, parent_pk)

    def make_unordered_list(self, parent=None):
        for pk, name, parent_pk in self.get_children(parent):
            self.make_unordered_list(pk)
```

Comment: I guess this code does to many db queries. Inspect the total queries with django debug toolbar or with `from django import db` and `print len(db.connection.queries)`. Does select_related boost the speed? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#select-related.  Also instead of `.exists()` you can do `null_list = Catagory.objects.filter(is_null=True)` and then see if your current category is in that list.

Comment: I cannot use select_related on children.
Here the error: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'children'. Choices are: parent

Comment: How many db queries does this code make?

Comment: I tried lot of different codes, and they took about 70+ queries without counting category.children.exists() and all the code below. Now i'm working on another approch, and i have 1 single query. ill post the result in the question as EDITED.

Comment: I removed some other code in the EDITED post, but it is clearly implicit!